# what is the brand of this sink faucet?

Tags: plumbing

[image: after taking out of the handle][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv4vB.jpg)One of my sink faucets in my bathroom is leaking and I decide to fix it. I can uninstall the handle using allen wrench but then don't know how to find the O-ring or something. I need to know the brand but I couldn't find any logo on it. I need to know the brand no matter whether I will fix it or just go buy a new one (to be the same). Can someone help to identify the brand?
enter image de[image: sink faucet]scription here

Comment: Getting brand information is going to be near impossible. Internationally there are many manufacturers that each make many models that they update every year or so.

Comment: For help here you will want to remove the leaky handle and then take a nice clear photo close up to the faucet that has the handle removed. Someone will most likely then be able to tell you the process for opening the valve.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: thanks. I was only able to update one picture and will upload more pictures.

Answer (score 1):

just looking at the surface and general look and fit and finish, it looks like a made in china junk faucet.  these types of faucets are essentially disposable.  even if you can get it apart (which may not be the case), you will never get parts for it.

if you do want to try it, try removing the supply line and nut from the bottom (under the counter) and lift the handle assembly out.  there may be a set screw or something under the escutcheon.  i have seen enough of these to not offer much hope though.  get yourself a moen faucet as a replacement.  good pricing, lots of choice, and free parts for life.

Comment: if I go buy a new moen faucet, what standard size should I ask? I found that some double handles are closer to each other than mine. There must be different sizes and setups.

Comment: @kornbor - Your faucet spacing was determined by the installer when the holes were drilled in the cabinet top. You would want to look for a replacement that has separate faucet handles that interconnect with hoses/tubing that can accommodate a range of faucet spacing. Fixed spacing come into play either when the sink has ready made holes for the faucets and/or the faucets and spout are designed as an integrated unit.

Answer (score 0):

The brand name of the faucet is often found facing the wall.
Put a hand mirror on the wall and illuminate it with a flashlight.